# magento white page on Admin System->configuration

Tags: magento, admin

I have to make some mods to an existing (and working) magento site. So I created a copy of the site in my computer and modified local.xml file, and core_config_data table.
I also put the local copy under a virtualname: "http://notela.dev".

Frontend works fine, and I'm able to login to admin and edit products but problem comes when I try to access system->config.

I just get a white page with no error. Neither error on magento or php log files.
I deleted all cached files and set permissions to 777 (just for testing pirpose) but nothing

- Requirements are OK
- PHP memory_limit is OK

¿what's happening?

Comment: I managed to find the problem: I deleted (mover in fact) all files under app/etc/modules except the Mage ones. Then the problem gone and I was able to open the admin page. Then I restored the files one by one until finding the module that was causing the problem.

Comment: Put that as an answer and accept it in due time. That is the SO way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find the problem: I deleted (moved in fact) all files under `app/etc/modules` except the `Mage` ones. Then the problem was solved and I was able to open the admin page. Then I restored the files one by one till I found the module that was causing the problem.